# How do I set the permissions of a samba share I mount via GNOME GUI?

Tags: gnome, permissions, samba, virtualization, cifs

When I mount a samba share on my NAS via the Gnome UI, it creates a folder named 'smb-share:server=192.168.1.1,share=data' in the /run/user/1000/gvfs folder.

The permission of this folder are restrictive : 0700 chown to only me.

I want to access a disk image in there with virt-manager to create a VM, but virt-manager gives me a permission denied error (screenshot below). (It seems virt-manager does not run as my user for some  step ?)

How can I tell Gnome that I want to mount this share with more permissive permissions? Or, how can I tell virt-manager to run fully under my user?

Thanks

[image: Permission denied error message]